# iPhone simulator doesn't see my NSString category

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I've an application with the following category for NSString:

```
@interface NSDate(ISO8601Parsing)



//This method is the one that does all the work. All the others are convenience methods.

+ (NSDate *)dateWithString:(NSString *)str strictly:(BOOL)strict getRange:(out NSRange *)outRange;

+ (NSDate *)dateWithString:(NSString *)str strictly:(BOOL)strict;



//Strictly: NO.

+ (NSDate *)dateWithString:(NSString *)str timeSeparator:(unichar)timeSep getRange:(out NSRange *)outRange;

+ (NSDate *)dateWithString:(NSString *)str timeSeparator:(unichar)timeSep;

+ (NSDate *)dateWithString:(NSString *)str getRange:(out NSRange *)outRange;

+ (NSDate *)dateWithString:(NSString *)str;



@end
```

The category is in the final application, not in a static library.
When I use the application on the iPhone (3GS with iOS4), there is no problem both with application and tests.
When I use the iPhone simulator my added methods aren't called. Debugging I've seen that xcode 'skips' the call and return null, very strange.
Any suggestion?
Thanks.
Jean

Comment: I'd try 'Clean All Targets' (off the build menu) first - you might have different half built bits of code for the simulator and the device. I"d uninstall it from both as well, just to be on the safe side :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue when using the code generated by wsdl2objc (see [issue](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/issues/detail?id=102)). I solved it by renaming one method:

```
+ (NSDate *)dateWithString:(NSString *)str
```

to e.g.

```
+ (NSDate *)wsdl2objcDateWithString:(NSString *)str;
```

It looks like a conflict between the code above and a new private API, but I'am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

rehos is correct - Thanks

**Just for extra clarity for noobs like myself;**

rename method in NSDate+ISO8601Parsing.m and .h

*and*

use renamed method in
 `+(NSDate *)deserializeNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur`